# Tensorflow GD does not change tf.Variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Thanks for looking into this question.

I am trying to train a 3-layer NN  to predict the stock price on next 10 days based on stock price in previous 15 days. While using the GradientDescentOptimizer, the weights of the variables have not changed, hence would like to seek some assistance from you. I have tried the following:

1. Check that there's a tf.placeholder and that I have fed in a tensor with correct dimension.
2. Changed the learning rate and see if loss improves.
3. Changed loss function from reduce_sum to reduce_mean of the squared differences between actual data and prediction.
4. Randomised my tf.Variables.

The code that I'm running is as follow. Some symbols are not defined here for clarity of the code. Appreciate your kind advice on this matter!

```
#Setting value placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(19,15,1), name = 'Input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(19,10,1), name = 'Output')


#Setting DNN key architectural values
n_layers = 3
n_nodes_l1 = 20
n_nodes_l2 = 30
n_nodes_l3 = 10

W01 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l1, 15],0,1,dtype=tf.float64,name="W01"))
W02 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l2, n_nodes_l1],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='W02')
W03 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l3, n_nodes_l2],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='W03')

b01 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l1,1],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='b01')
b02 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l2,1],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='b02') 
b03 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l3,1],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='b03')


#Building the architecture
def neural(X):

    a01 = tf.matmul(W01, X) + b01
    X2 = tf.sigmoid(a01)

    a02 = tf.matmul(W02, X2) + b02
    X3 = tf.sigmoid(a02)

    a03 = tf.matmul(W03, X3) + b03
    y_prediction= tf.sigmoid(a03)

    return y_prediction

#Loss and Optimizer
loss = []
final_loss= []
y_pred_col = []

for n_batch in range(0,len(x_data)):
    y_pred = neural(x[n_batch])
    y_pred_col.append(y_pred)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y_pred_col))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)

#Setting up Tensor Session
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

n_steps = 30
for iter in range(n_steps):
    _, l, W01_train = sess.run([optimizer,loss,W01], feed_dict = {x: x_data, y_: y_data})
    print(l)
```

Comment: What's the idea behind the loop `for n_batch in range(0,len(x_data))`? I believe the problem comes from there

Comment: Hi Rvinas, thanks for your swift reply! So x_data has dimension of (19,15,1), i.e 19 sets of (15,1) array. So x[0] is selecting the 1st set of (15,1) data. The loop is so that I could get a column of y_pred based on the NN. With this, I can then define the loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do things a bit differently. There is something that doesn't make sense in your code:

```
for n_batch in range(0,len(x_data)):
    y_pred = neural(x[n_batch])
    y_pred_col.append(y_pred)
```

Here, each call of `neural` is creating a new neural network, so you end up having `len(x_data)` networks. I pressume that you want a single network. In that case, you should be calling `neural` only once:

```
y_pred = neural(x)
```

This will require you to define the [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul) operations from `neural` in a different way (as now you need to take the first dimension of `X` into account). The loss function will then be defined as:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y_pred))
```

Putting it all together:

```
#Setting value placeholder
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None,15), name = 'Input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None,10), name = 'Output')

#Setting DNN key architectural values
n_layers = 3
n_nodes_l1 = 20
n_nodes_l2 = 30
n_nodes_l3 = 10

W01 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([15, n_nodes_l1],0,1,dtype=tf.float64,name="W01"))
W02 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l1, n_nodes_l2],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='W02')
W03 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l2, n_nodes_l3],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='W03')

b01 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l1],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='b01')
b02 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l2],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='b02')
b03 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_l3],0,1,dtype=tf.float64),name='b03')


#Building the architecture
def neural(X):
    a01 = tf.matmul(X, W01) + b01
    X2 = tf.sigmoid(a01)

    a02 = tf.matmul(X2, W02) + b02
    X3 = tf.sigmoid(a02)

    a03 = tf.matmul(X3, W03) + b03
    y_prediction= tf.sigmoid(a03)

    return y_prediction

#Loss and Optimizer
y_pred = neural(x)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y_pred))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(loss)

#Setting up Tensor Session
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

n_steps = 30

for iter in range(n_steps):
    _, l, W01_train = sess.run([optimizer,loss,W01], feed_dict = {x: x_data, y_: y_data})
    print(l)
```

Note that I changed the definition of the placeholders and weights for convenience. The code above will run provided that the shapes of `x_data` and `y_data` are `(batch_size=19,15)` and `(batch_size=19,10)`, respectively. If the problem still remains after this modifications then it is probably due to other reasons (i.e. dependent on your data or hyperparameters).